# Trouble tweeting from R?

Tags: r, twitter

I was wondering if anybody on here has any experience using the Twitter API in R? I'm trying to set up a simple Twitter bot with an R script but seem to be running into a problem with my access to twitter's API. I'm using the package Rtweet, I have a developer account set up on Twitter and I believe the token information is entered correctly. I followed the example from this blog post: https://www.interhacktives.com/2021/03/16/how-to-scrape-open-data-and-tweet-it-using-a-bot-with-r/

When I run my code, I get an error message when I try to use the function "post_tweet". The error message is as follows: "You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: [https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve"](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve%22) I've been up and down the Twitter developer dashboard and I thought that my level of access would allow me to send a simple tweet, but maybe I'm wrong?

Does anybody have any insight here? I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: I do not think the `rtweet` package supports the v2 create Tweet endpoint, so it is calling the v1.1 endpoint and that requires the elevated option, not essential access. You could check the details with the library project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.